# Is it possible to serve media files by Django on Production with static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Tags: django

I want to use non-static images for my app. Meaning that Admin will be able to upload images (and create articles). Users will have read-only access to articles.

Would in this case it be possible to use function [static()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) on Production to store and serve images?

```
static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Or still I should use only 3rd party resource for storing/serving the images?

Comment: What kind of security issues come to your mind? Non-admins shouldn't be able to see these images?

Comment: - Just any potential security issues: like getting access to server file system, uploading and running malicious scripts on the server, etc. The Django docs states that MEDIA_ROOT/MEDIA_URL should only be used for development reasons - I'm curious why can not I use it for Production in my case

- Non-admins should be able to see the images

Comment: `MEDIA_ROOT/MEDIA_URL should only be used for development reasons` docs don't say that. Serving static/media files with django engine is not recommended in prod because of performance concerns. These files are static and can be served by web server with no need to run any python code. "Serving" means handling requests to get those files from server. Everything else is just fine. "Malicious script" is out of scope of Django, Django-admin and anything starting with `MEDIA_`.

Comment: "During development, you can serve user-uploaded media files from MEDIA_ROOT using the django.views.static.serve() view.

This is not suitable for production use!" - this is the quote from docs :)

Regarding "static files", STATIC_ROOT or STATIC_URL I don't have any questions.

What interests me is MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL and "media files" - files uploaded by a user - in my case by admin. They are not static, I need to be able to upload/delete them at any time.

Comment: Using of `django.views.static.serve()` view is not suitable for production.

Comment: That's true - docs say just that, but maybe you could give more details on why is that? Let's say I will use it for Production - what bad can happen? :)

Comment: Please reread second comment of mine (upvoted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer happened to be very simple:

the function

```
static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

simply won't work with "Debug = false".

That's why it can not be used on Production.
Here is a quote from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development]):

> This helper function works only in debug mode and only if the given prefix is local (e.g. /media/) and not a URL (e.g. http://media.example.com/).

Comment: This quote has nothing to do with your original question as well as with _serving media files in prod with django_. It describes specific **helper function** behavior only. Not media files in general, not performance or "securitiy" issues.

Comment: @IvanStarostin even though that quote answered my question I agree with you. I will try to rename the question according to the answer so that it can be helpful for others

Comment: `static()` does not _serve_ anything. It is a **helper** function for including **correct** url patterns for static/media files "automatically". One can add such patterns manually and still _serve_ static/media files with Django. Which is still not recommended.